# how to save a column name which has a space using AS keyword

Tags: u-sql

I am trying to save the column name using AS keyword in u-sql as:
`AS 'first name'`
It gives me the error: Quoted identifier are not enabled by default. Can someone help me on how to do this?

Comment: Would you mind sharing a relevant table structure and the query?

Comment: @Sasha, it could be any structure.  This problem persists everywhere. When I save with a string that has a "space"

Comment: Very interesting. Seems like square brackets should work? `In order to allow arbitrary identifiers that are either keywords or contain any Unicode code point, U-SQL allows to quote identifiers using [ and ]`, from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/concepts/identifiers/identifiers